# DELETE FROM processes whole table?

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a table with "Total logical bytes" of 45.85 GB, clustered on a field `EventId`. Each event has somewhere around 10k-100k rows. When trying to run

```sql
DELETE FROM <table> WHERE EventId=<eventId>;
```

on this table, I see `This query will process 45.84 GB when run` which seems to indicate that it's not using the "clustered on" field but rather scanning the entire table? Is that right, or is there a way to do this "cheaper", processing-wise? Or perhaps I'm missing something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per Bigquery documentation:

"`When you query a clustered table, you don't receive an accurate query cost estimate before query execution because the number of storage blocks to be scanned is not known before query execution. The final cost is determined after query execution is complete and is based on the specific storage blocks that were scanned.`
" [Ref:https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/clustered-tables]

Best way to check it out is to run a sample query and look into "Bytes processed" and "Bytes billed" after the job is done and you will see that it's less than the entire table scan.

Clustering does not guarantee the same way as partitioned by field.

If you really want, you can try partitioning it by integer field if your data allows it. [Ref: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/creating-partitioned-tables#create_an_integer-range_partitioned_table].